# app_WindowSelectionChange for Just One File VBA Word

Tags: vba

I have a Macro Word file that controls a non-macro word file (this allows collaboration in the non-macro word file, note macro Word files don't allow simultaneous editing).

The Macro Word file has a treeview and populates it with data from the non-macro word file and the treeview expands when the non-macro word file cursor is changed.  The macro also has some forward / backward buttons for navigating the non-macro word file.

I get the cursor position with app_WindowSelectionChange; however, this sub activates even if i'm clicking in a 3rd word document. People often have 3-10 word documents open and reference while using this macro.  I need to get the document name where the mouse clicks fed into this app_WindowSelectionChange sub, so I can bypass the sub if the user has a 3rd unrelated word document up they are referencing.

like ideally i just add something like this, but it doesn't work

```
If currentDocName <> docName Then Exit Sub
```

here is the selection change code

```
Sub app_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    On Error Resume Next
    'If currentDocName <> docName Then Exit Sub
     
    If backState = False And forwardState = False Then
    Dim currentparagraph As Integer
    currentparagraph = Documents(docName).Range(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
    
    If navColl.Count = 0 Then navColl.Add currentparagraph
      If navColl.Count > 0 Then
        If navColl(navColl.Count) <> currentparagraph Then
           navColl.Add currentparagraph
           navCollpos = navColl.Count
        End If
      End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Here is an image of the macro word user form next to the non-macro word document used for collaboration:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Selection.Range.Parent.Name` to retrieve documents name of selection.

Comment: This is the answer, i can't believe how simple it is. Thank you so much!!! seriously, appreciate the help! i use selection.range in that sub, but wasn't able to drag my knuckles to the parent.name bit

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem :-) . See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)